# Strange behavior with integers

Tags: objective-c

I am learning how to program using Objective C/C++ (using Xcode 5). I have a basic code right now on how to calculate the area of a rectangle.

```
int main()
{
    //Step 1. Declare the Variables
    int rectangleWidth, rectangleLength, rectangleArea;

    //Step 2: Initialize The Variables
    rectangleWidth = 4.0;
    rectangleLength = 5.0;

    //Step 3: Calculations
    rectangleArea = rectangleWidth * rectangleLength;
}
```

When I run it I get massive numbers like:

```
rectangleLength int 1606422622  1606422622
rectangleWidth  int 32767   32767
rectangleArea   int 32767   32767
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Data type is `int` but you're initializing with `float`. Did you try running code without decimal points? So 4 and 5 instead of 4.0 and 5.0.

Comment: it is working fine for me

Comment: @bytefire I thought it could be that, but I was pretty sure it shoud work and it's ok for me: I have "20" as an output for rectangleArea.I think it's due to the output/print method.

Comment: How are you displaying the output results?

Answer (score 3):

> Any Idea?

Sure. Somewhere along the line you're mixing types inappropriately. There's an example of that in this line:

```
rectangleWidth = 4.0;
```

Here you're assigning a floating point number to an int. As Till points out in the comments, the compiler should take care of that for you by converting the value for you. However, if you made that mistake, you're likely also making it in other places. You don't explain how you're viewing the results -- checking them in the debugger, printing them to the console, etc. You also don't tell us exactly how you've built this program -- is it an actual iOS app, a Foundation-based Mac command line program, etc.? Those details matter, at least as far as duplicating your exact results goes. For example, building as an iOS app I get the following results:

```
rectangleLength = 8.48798e-314
rectangleWidth = -1.99558
rectangleArea = 4.36328e-313
```

when I display the variables using `NSLog()` with the following line:

```
NSLog(@"rectangleLength = %g\nrectangleWidth = %g\nrectangleArea = %g", rectangleLength, rectangleWidth, rectangleArea);
```

Of ours, using `%g` as the format specifier is wrong -- the variables are of type `int`, so I should use a format specifier that expects that type. Changing the `%g` to `%d` yields correct results:

```
rectangleLength = 5
rectangleWidth = 4
rectangleArea = 20
```

Whatever the exact details of your program, the lessons here are:

- Be aware of the types that you're using.
- Don't mix type inappropriately.
- Make sure that interpret the data using the correct type.

Comment: Why exactly does type conversion fail to work here - mind that he is not using pointers?

Comment: Doesn't this `rectangleWidth = 4.0;` try to assign a double to an int rather than float?

Comment: @EdChum sure - double precision floating point, but that is a bit of nitpicking, I'ld say.

Comment: @Till agree but I was unsure if objective-c followed the same rules as C++ so I was curious

Comment: @Till Great point, and I agree with you that the output method is a likely culprit. I've rewritten this post to try to cover that.

Comment: Much better ... revoked downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Actally, it should work even if as Caleb said you should write

```
rectangleWidth = 4;
```

instead

or declare

```
float rectangleWidth, rectangleLength, rectangleArea;
```

Try my code: **(Note: I didn't get if you were using C,C++,Objective C or Objective C++, so here is some C++ code)**

```
#include<iostream>
int main()                                                                                                                                                                
{
    //Step 1. Declare the Variables
    float rectangleWidth, rectangleLength, rectangleArea;

    //Step 2: Initialize The Variables
    rectangleWidth = 4.0;
    rectangleLength = 5.0;

    //Step 3: Calculations
    rectangleArea = rectangleWidth * rectangleLength;
    std::cout << rectangleArea << std::endl;
}
```

I think your output system is wrong